# @CallSuper Annotation and UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, android

I have a method that has the `@CallSuper` annotation, which forces sub classes to call `super.methodName()`. A subclass overrides this method and tries to throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`, but the compiler is still complaining that I haven't called the super method. Is there an easy way around this?

Comment: Do you call the super.methodName?

Comment: No i don't call it, and I'd rather not have to. That's why the compiler is complaining.

Comment: So why don't you remove @CallSuper?

Comment: I could do that, but I think it makes sense to have it there, because in every other case I need to CallSuper.

Comment: Why do you want to throw a UnsupportedOperationException?Does somewhere say that if your don't call super.methodName(),it will throw UnsupportedOperationException?Please remove @CallSuper if you don't want to add super.methodName().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that I can just suppress the warning with `@SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")`.